# Sentencia switch de Javascript no está tomando los datos y como resultado arroja "is not defined" por la consola del navegador

Tags: javascript, funciones, function, undefined, switch

En este código Javascript se intenta simular la compra de productos para calcular su precio total. El problema es que dentro del switch no está tomando los datos en la sentencia case, es decir, no encuentra ninguna coincidencia cuando debería hacerlo, arrojando por la consola que "Uncaught ReferenceError: cantidad is not defined at calcularPrecio at HTMLFormElement". Por este motivo no se logra determinar el precio de los productos y por consiguiente el subtotal.

Intuyo que el value que trae el select no se actualiza y es siempre el mismo, por lo cual entonces no se ingresa en ninguno de los dos case del switch

Quise agregar este código:

```
let cantidad = parseInt(document.querySelector('cantidad'.value));
```

y este:

```
let cantidad = Number( document.getElementById('cantidad').value );
```

para poder definir cantidad pero no funcionó, aún modificando el id de Quantity por cantidad del html...

```
let productType = document.getElementById("productType").value;
let precio = "";

function calcularPrecio() {

switch (productType) {
  case "Producto1":
    if (cantidad < 6) {
      precio = 330;
    } else if (cantidad >= 6 && cantidad <= 11) {
      precio = 243;
    } else if (cantidad > 11 && cantidad <= 24) {
      precio = 225;
    } else {
      precio = 216;
    }
    break;
  case "Producto2":
    if (cantidad < 6) {
      precio = 251;
    } else if (cantidad >= 6 && cantidad <= 11) {
      precio = 179;
    } else if (cantidad > 11 && cantidad <= 24) {
      precio = 172;
    } else {
      precio = 165;
    }
    break;
  default:
    precio = "No se pudo calcular el precio";
}
}


const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  calcularPrecio();
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  let tableRef = document.getElementById("table");
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
  
  let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  newCell.textContent = formData.get("productType")

  newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
  newCell.textContent = formData.get("Quantity")
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
  newCell.textContent = precio;
}

)



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cotizador Online</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/styles.css">

    <!--Font Awesome-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Cotizador Online</h1>
    <form id="form">
    <div>
    <label for="productType">Producto</label>
    <select id="productType" name="productType" >
        <option value="Seleccione el producto">Seleccione el producto</option>
        <option value="Producto1">Arroz</option>
        <option value="Producto2">Manteca</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="Quantity">Cantidad</label>
    <input id="Quantity" type="number" name="Quantity">
    </div>
    <div>
    <button>Agregar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div>
        <table id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>

        
<script src="/JS/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ese problema ya se había resuelto en una pregunta pasada. De hecho sigo viendo que tienes el mismo error de antes, no lo has corregido, por eso no funciona.

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que al manipular mas el DOM no lograba dar con el error y haciendo lo anterior tampoco... sin embargo lo logré solucionar un poco mas de 1 hora después de la publicación... ¿debería eliminar la pregunta @AlbertoSiurob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu script debe quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
let precio = "";

function calcularPrecio() {
  let productType = document.getElementById("productType").value;
  let cantidad = document.getElementById("Quantity").value;

  switch (productType) {
    case "Producto1":
      if (cantidad < 6) {
        precio = 330;
      } else if (cantidad >= 6 && cantidad <= 11) {
        precio = 243;
      } else if (cantidad > 11 && cantidad <= 24) {
        precio = 225;
      } else {
        precio = 216;
      }
      break;
    case "Producto2":
      if (cantidad < 6) {
        precio = 251;
      } else if (cantidad >= 6 && cantidad <= 11) {
        precio = 179;
      } else if (cantidad > 11 && cantidad <= 24) {
        precio = 172;
      } else {
        precio = 165;
      }
      break;
    default:
      precio = "No se pudo calcular el precio";
  }
}

const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  calcularPrecio();
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  let tableRef = document.getElementById("table");
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);

  let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  newCell.textContent = formData.get("productType");

  newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
  newCell.textContent = formData.get("Quantity");
  newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
  newCell.textContent = precio;
});
```

Debes ver que resultado esperas, actualmente estarías devolviendo el costo unitario en base a la cantidad. Si deseas el total deberías multiplicar el costo unitario por la cantidad(acá si sería necesario pasarla a number)

---

Esto en ambos casos está mal declarado, tu input tiene Id Quantity, hice esa modificación en el script, y la declaración de los valores debe hacerse dentro de la función calcularPrecio, ya que si se hace antes, tomará los valores que tienen los input antes de lanzar la función.

```
let cantidad = parseInt(document.querySelector('cantidad'.value)); 

let cantidad = Number( document.getElementById('cantidad').value );
```